# SOLR Indexing Performance: Processing 2.3k Docs/s

Tags: solr, lucene

Im trying to improve performance of my Solr 6.0 Index.

Originally we were indexing 45m rows that was using a select statement joining 7 table and taking 7+ hours to index. This caused us to get a snapshot too old error while the jdbc connection is open for the entire duration of the indexing. Causing our full index to fail.

We were able to archive about 10m rows and build an external table from the original 7 join select. This simplified the query solr was using so a select * from 1 table.

Now are indexing 35m rows using a Select * from ONE_BIG_*External*-TABLE now and it's taking ~4-5 hrs @ 2.3k docs/s +-250. Since we are using an external table we shouldn't be getting the snap shot too old because of the UNDO stack.

*We have 77 columns we are indexing.*

So we found a solution for our initial issue but now I'm looking to increase our indexing speed when doing clean fulls.

[Referencing SolrPerformanceFactors](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors) I have tried:

- Batch Sizes:

  1. 2000 - no change
  2. 6000 - no change
  3. 4000 - no change

Example:

```
 <dataSource jndiName="xxxxxx batchSize="2000" type="JdbcDataSource"/>
```

- Autocommit:

  1. Every 1 hour - no change
- MergeFactor:

  1. 20 vs 10 default - shed off 20 mins
- Indexed Fields:

  1. Cut out 11 indexed fields - nothing

EDIT: Adding some information per questions below. I did auto-commits to every hour which didn't help any. Also soft commit every second. I copied a much smaller solr core we have here that had these parameters and they said they have been running well.

```
    <autoCommit> 
      <maxTime>3600000</maxTime> 
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
    </autoCommit>


    <autoSoftCommit> 
      <maxTime>1000</maxTime> 
    </autoSoftCommit>
```

Is there any gotchas that I'm missing other than throwing hardware at this? 
Let me know if you need more info, I'll try answer questions as best as I'm allowed.

Comment: Did you try to alter [ramBufferSizeMB or maxBufferedDocs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/indexconfig-in-solrconfig.html#IndexConfiginSolrConfig-maxBufferedDocs) within the indexConfig of your solrconfig?

Comment: Do the data you load have any column/property that would allow partitioning? Something like category or alike. This would allow to split the data into several queries.

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to move away from DIH to a custom indexer when you're starting to experience performance issues - that'll allow you to use multiple CPU cores, index to different nodes for speedup (i.e. distributed processing) and avoid having to create the single, large table on the DB side. It'll also allow you to tweak the commit size (and what is your commit settings?) to avoid actually committing before everything has been submitted.

Comment: @MatsLindh We did change the commit timing. It hard commits every hour and soft commits ever second. I added it to my question. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @cheffe I havnt changed the ramBufferSizeMB or maxBufferedDoc. Its not even in my solrConfig so im assuming its set to default.  Right now we share our solr server with 7 other cores (<500k docs each). We have had problems with running out of memory in the past so I was leary to change this. I have a service request to get my own solr instance so maybe I can tinker with this setting once its spun up.

Comment: For very high indexing rates I would increase the softCommit a LOT e.g. 5 minutes at least. If you can batch together changes. Beyond that I found that "throwing CPU" at the problem worked well if you have high rates of change as the analysis/indexing is CPU intensive.